# What does "調子の良い事" mean when used with "言って"?

Tags: translation

I was browsing #アカギ on pixiv when I found this one. https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=16943272.

It's this line.

> 調子の良い事を言って原田に刺される健

I've also heard it used just as

> 調子の良い事言って...

Does it mean like "saying good things". Why isn't "compliment" or "praise" used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

調子の良い事を言う has a negative nuance like "He says fine things to try to gain favor."

People who says 調子の良い事 is often regarded as a master of double-talk, everybody’s friend.

Comment: I see. So It's like calling someone a "smooth-talker" or "flattterer"?

Comment: I think it is close to a flatterer.